# Using the IF statement formula below, can I make any bank holiday dates regardless of time to theatre show as "out of hours" ? using a named range

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, named-ranges

```
=IF(AND(MOD(J2,1)>TIME(8,15,0),MOD(J2,1)<TIME(17,0,0)),"In hours","Out of Hours")
```

Formatted for readability:

```
=IF(
    AND(
        MOD( J2, 1 )  >  TIME(  8, 15, 0 ),
        MOD( J2, 1 )  <  TIME( 17,  0, 0 )
    ),
    "In hours",
    "Out of Hours"
)
```

UK bank holidays financial year 23-24:

```
07/04/2023
10/04/2023
01/05/2023
08/05/2023
29/05/2023
28/08/2023
25/12/2023
26/12/2023
01/01/2024
29/03/2024
```

Comment: What does that formula have to do with "bank holidays" and "time to theatre" (whatever that means????) Is the data you are sharing (the list of dates) the same data you are running this function against. If so, none of these dates have a time component to even compare. Please share more about your data and what you are trying to do. Please also move your question into the body and out of the title. See the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article for more guidance on cleaning this up so it is answerable.

Comment: Excel has `IF` _functions_, or expressions, not statements.

Comment: Dai the tag on Stack overflow has if-statement

Comment: I am sorry for not making this clear as I am not an expert with formulas. The excel formula is looking at a date and time field that a person goes to theatre.  If the time is within 08:00 and 17:00 it is shown as "within hours" else out of hours.  Some of the dates can be bank holidays and may be within hours.  However bank holiday dates need to return "out of hours: regardless of the time. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your clarification helps a lot. Assuming that your list of bank holidays is in Q1:Q10 (just as an example, you can modify your current `if` to look something like: `=IF(AND(MOD(J2,1)>TIME(8,15,0),MOD(J2,1)<TIME(17,0,0)),IF(countif($Q$1:$Q$10), INT(J2), "Out of Hours", "In hours"),"Out of Hours")`

Comment: Hi thank you for trying to help me.  Unfortunately I get an error message stating 'you've entered too few arguments for this function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweaking JNevill's formula I did the following: I first check the list of bank holidays for the match, if that causes and error because it's not a bank holiday it then validates as it previously did; however, if it doesn't produce an error, that means it's a bank holiday therefore it is labelled "Out of Hours". Modify ranges as necessary.

`=IF(ISERROR( VLOOKUP(INT(J2) ,$Q$1:$Q$10,1,0)) ,IF(AND(MOD(J2,1)>TIME(8,15,0),MOD(J2,1)<TIME(17,0,0)),"In hours","Out of Hours"),"Out of Hours")`

Comment: Amazing your answer works perfectly.  Thank you so much for taking the time to help and I apologise for the delay.  I have only just tried it now.